# How to move an element to the third position with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Please, help me with this. I have:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Headline for element 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quosque tandem.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Headline for element 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quosque tandem.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Headline for element 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quosque tandem.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Headline for element 4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quosque tandem.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Headline for element 5</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quosque tandem.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And this is what I want to do:

- Every time you click on a list item, it moves to the center position (3rd position) and applies the class "active".

I have this in jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var third = $("ul li:eq(1)");

$("ul li").click(function() {
$("ul li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
$(this).insertAfter(third);
$(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
});
});
```

But it doesn't work for the first and the second element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"But it doesn't work for the first and the second element."*

That's because when you move the item the other items move up to fill the gap. I'd suggest you first [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) the item in question and *then* calculate the middle position within the remaining elements before re-inserting the detached item.

Note also that the variable that you create here:

```
var third = $("ul li:eq(1)");
```

...will refer to the second item in the list *as it was when the document was first loaded.* It does *not* automatically update to refer to the second item when the list is reordered. (Also, it doesn't make sense to have a variable called `third` that refers to the *second* item.) You need to calculate the middle position within your `.click()` handler:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul li").click(function() {
    $("li.active").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    var $active = $(this).detach().addClass("active"),
        $lis = $("ul li");
    $active.insertBefore($lis.eq(Math.floor($lis.length / 2)));
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/avupud/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to `$(this).insertAfter("ul li:eq(1)");`